# Angular router-outlet content overlaid on top of mat-toolbar

Tags: html, angular

In my app.component.html, I placed a mat-toolbar above a router-outlet like so:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Tattoo Share!</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The problem is the router-outlet content is overlaid on top of the toolbar. This content should be beneath the toolbar. How should I correct this? I tried placing things inside block elements such as div to no avail. There is also this CSS on mat-toolbar:
`mat-toolbar { position: fixed }`

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz of your setup? Look at this https://angular-ivy-bxvzxv.stackblitz.io/home I had the same code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work using some CSS on my toolbar:

```
mat-toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS in the `styles.css` to put a margin-bottom equals to the height of the toolbar in itself. Also use an ID so it won’t apply to other toolbars

```
mat-toolbar#over-router {
    margin-bottom: 40px; // check the actual height in the browser
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Router-outlet content is still over top the toolbar.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz or a repo with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex layout.

```
<div class="home-main">
     <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
     <div class="home-container">
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>
</div>

.home-main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```